# asp.net core html helper tag - set value (datetime) client side - format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

in my json i've this date generated  by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`

`2020-05-11T15:27:50.3666678+02:00`

I get this json by jquery ajax call and i need to set this value (client-side) to an html helper tag

to set this field client-side i do:

`$("#scandate").val(details.ScanDate);`

where scandate contains the date in the format above `2020-05-11T15:27:50.3666678+02:00`

but i got this error:

```
The specified value "2020-05-11T14:41:59.5753508+02:00" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".
```

trying to pass a (fixed) date like this `2020-05-11T15:27:50` the component shows the date!

how can i adjust it avoiding to do a brutal subtring in order remove the last part of the date?

Comment: Do you try to get sub string of `details.ScanDate` then set it as value of your input filed in js code logic? Besides, if you can share more relevant code of your model class and view page, we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: yes @Fei Han, i did exactly this and works. I was just wondering if there is a method to instruct the html helper to accept a differnt format